# Powershell Script to extract Outlook .msg files Data and Rename .msg file

Tags: powershell, email, scripting, admin, email-attachments

I'm a bit embarrassed to say that I have basically 0 knowledge or experience with scripts, and python to me is a snake, but I found this forum and I am hoping I can at least get a point in the right direction if not an out right answer... Maybe someone has done this exact thing before and its easy for you, or you can give me a link to a website that might have an answer?

The extent of my knowledge in this field is using a basic 1 line script in powershell to add a suffix to a file name which I found on google. Sooo the above is wayyyyyy past my experience level... :(

I work on a team of admins who process files all day and since were an older crowd, we do things very manually, but I'm trying to learn to make our lives easier. I know there is magic that can be done with "scripts" or powershell that I have seen and I am hoping an extremely tedious task can be automated. We don't have an IT department that would be willing to help with this and my manager doesn't care, but I think it could be a great help to productivity. I have access to Microsoft power apps which I am trying to learn, but very limited in outside software due to security not letting us.

Regularly, we will have a file folder with 100+ .msg files from outlook. The task is to open each .msg in the folder, and if there are attachments, we save them one by one and rename them so they are in the same folder.

Say the .msg is titled "email.msg" and it has 3 attachments. A .PDF, a .xls, and a .Doc.

We need to save each attachment to the same folder the .msg is in (currently open folder) and rename them to "email_attach 1 of 3.pdf", "email_attach 2 of 3.xls", and "email_attach 3 of 3. doc"

In the folder they need to be listed like the below:

email.msg

email_attach 1 of 3.pdf

email_attach 2 of 3.xls

email_attach 3 of 3.doc

doesn't matter what order the attachments are saved in, just that the attachments have the name of the original email (not the original attachment file name - couldn't care less about that), followed by _attach 1 of # (# being the total number of attachments)

rinse and repeat for every .msg in the folder...

I don't suppose any kind and generous soul is willing to help out a dinosaur? Can this even be done easily? Do I need to request special software?

I haven't tried anything because I have no idea what to do. My experience is low enough that I would just copy and paste something from the web and hope for the best. This script or programming language thing is way out of my field... I know holding shift and right clicking opens powershell....

I found some scripts that might work to pull attachments, but not rename them. I don't need to save to a specific file path, just to the currently open folder I am working in

Answer (score 1):

You can use the com object of an Outlook client. There are 2 requirements: you need to have Outlook application installed & Outlook application cannot be running during script execution (close it before launching the script).

Remember to update the path in the first line according to your need. Here is a sample script:

```
$path = "C:\Temp\emails"
$outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.msg | ForEach-Object {
    $file = $outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate($_.FullName)
    $emailName = $_.Name
    $counter = 1
    $file.Attachments | ForEach-Object { 
        $extension = $_.FileName[($_.FileName.LastIndexOf("."))..($_.FileName.Length)] -join('')
        $emailName = $emailName.Replace(".msg",'')
        $name = "$($emailName)_attach $counter of $($file.Attachments.count)$extension"
        $_.saveAsFile("$path\$name")
        $counter++
    }
}
$outlook.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Outlook)
```

Comment: Outlook doesn’t have to be closed.